# Is there a simpler way to sum the first $n$ terms of the sequence of numbers starting at 2 and squaring to get the next?

Tags: summation, computer-science, power-towers

I've got this summation:

$$
f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{2^i}
$$

In effect, it's the sum of the sequence of numbers you get from starting at 2 and squaring the previous number in the sequence:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a(0) &= 2 \\
a(n) &= a(n-1)^2 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

(It's [this sequence in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001146) I'm summing, or the $n$th term of [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A060803) I'm searching for, for context.)

Obviously, if it were just summing the powers of two, I could get rid of the summation pretty easily:

$$
f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i \\
f(n)=\frac{1-2^n}{1-2} \\
f(n)=-(1-2^n) \\
f(n)=2^n - 1 \\
$$

This is supposed to be for computing optimization, so most elementary operations are generally pretty fast. I just want to get rid of that giant sigma and be able to just do it in terms of [elementary arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic) and preferably without exponentiation with a base of anything other than a power of 2.

```
# My goal is to avoid this kind of code
def f(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, n - 1):
        sum += 2 ** (2 ** i)
    return sum
```

Comment: I doubt there's a closed formula at all, much less one that's faster to compute than the code you included.

Comment: The first element is $2$, not $1$. Without the typo, it is [sequence A001146](https://oeis.org/A001146) in OEIS.

Comment: $f(n)$ has a pretty regular form in binary. It's not a closed form, but bitwise arithmetic (e.g. bitshift) might be somewhat fast.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks! Updated.

Comment: @user326210 I'm aware bitwise arithmetic would make it faster, but I still can't avoid the loop regardless and that's what I'm hoping to get rid of. That's the goal of this question, to get rid of the loop.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows the loop will not be a issue, the size of the number will be. Let's say $n = 10$, you are only summing 10 numbers but the last number has over $150$ digits When $n = 20$, you are only summing 20 numbers but the last number has over $1.5\times 10^5$ digits....